# Optimal Stopping Problem - Is There a Point Where the Next Result Is Statistically Insignificant to the Overall Result?

Tags: probability, statistics

## Context

Hello, all! I'm a Spanish teacher by trade, but I'm something of an armchair mathematician. Currently, I'm grading midterm exams and, pursuant to department policy, I have to give points back for any multiple-choice question with less than 50% success rate amongst the students. I have a bunch of tentative grades but, since many of my students have not completed the exam (requiring extra time), the sample population is incomplete. This got the maths gears in my head turning. The problem I present here is a simplified version of the problem I'm facing in real life but, without mathematical training, I don't know how to solve this problem or if it is even solvable.

## The Problem

You are flipping a coin $t$ times. The goal is to have heads come up more than 50% of the time. Is there a number of flips, $n$, where a definitive conclusion about whether heads will make up more than 50% of the data set or must the data be complete? If so, what is the value of $n$?

Additional notes:

- $(t\in [0, \infty))\land (t\in\mathbb{N})$
- $(n\in[0, t))\land (n\in\mathbb{N})$

## Attempts to Solve

### Harmonic Series

Originally, I thought that it would be possible to get an upper bound for the influence of the next flip, $n+1$, by realising that the influence would be $\in \{0, \frac{1}{n+1}\}$. Naturally, this would also diminish the value of each previous success. Thus, if we simplify slightly by assuming that it would simply add that value to the previous value, we can see that the first flips would be $\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}\dots$. Obviously, this grows to be larger than $1$ if we don't take the first few flips into consideration, but this would yield that the maximum influence would be $\sum_{i=n}^{t}\left(\frac{1}{i} \right)$ or the discrete sum of the Harmonic Series. If we only care about the rate of change between two points (obviously, we'd want to minimise this to not have one value switch the overall percentage of heads by too much), we could treat this as a continuous function and integrate: $\int_n^t \frac{1}{x} dx$ which evaluates to $\ln(t)-\ln(n)$ or simply $\ln\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)$. If we evaluate $\lim_{n\to t}\left(\ln\left(\frac{t}{n} \right) \right)$, we find that the limit is $0$. (Here, for simplicity, we'll define $\forall x: \frac{x}{0}=1$. This allows us to see that the first flip makes a world of difference --- the whole difference. Alternatively, we could rewrite the function to be that the denominator is $n+1$ and the limit is evaluated $n\to t-1$.)

When I wrote a programme to test these numbers quickly, I found that the percentages seemed intuitive (ie, the large the sample or the smaller unknown values, the smaller the influence would be), but these were returning values (when divided by $t$) in the range of about $[0.4, 0.52]$ which, obviously is wrong. So, I quickly decided that this must be an upper bound (a *far* one at that) that, as $n\to t$, decreases reasonably. The problem I see with this is that $n$ has to get almost unreasonably close to not just finish the sample, but I also know that this cannot be the case.

### Theoretical Proof of Concept (Non-Rigourous)

Theoretically, if $t=100$ and the first $51$ flips are all heads, then you can tell right there an then. Obviously this is *ridiculously* unlikely, but it is indeed possible. It would stand to reason, then, that one would have to wait for the number of success to constitute 50% of the data set (ie, $n \geq \frac{t}{2}$) and then wait for another success. This means that the feasible values for $n$ (call it $n_s$ for 'solutions for $n$) would have to be thus stated: $n_s\in[\lfloor\frac{t}{2} \rfloor+1, t]$. This seems rather dissatisfying owing to the fact that, with an unlucky string of flips after $n=\lfloor\frac{t}{2} \rfloor$ could lead to one needing to gather more and more data until the point where it may make more sense to just do all of them.

### Another Stopping Problem Which May or May Not Be Related

I remember seeing a video by Numberphile on YouTube which indicated that, if one wanted to pick the best bathroom to use from a finite list of $b$ bathrooms, it was best to recall which was the highest rated of the first $\frac{b}{e}$ of them and then pick the nest best one. If memory serves, this would yield in having picked the best bathroom (or highest number, as was done in a similar VSauce2 video) $\frac{1}{e}$ of the time. I quickly dismissed this thought, but I'm curious to know if I merely need that few of them to be able to draw a conclusion on this matter.

## Conclusion

Obviously, the coin flipping is simplified from the original student question, but it could be seen as similar as it is (from my point of view) just as random as a coin toss. Has anybody solved this problem? Is it solvable? And, if it is solvable, what is $n_s$?

Thank you all for your help in advance!